# Xamarin based Mac OSX app deployment size

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I'm thinking about porting a .NET based desktop application to Mac using the Xamarin.Mac platform. I can't seem to find any info about deployment size of the resulting application. Is it like Xamarin iOS development i.e. the C# code is natively compiled into mac code and I don't have to worry about distributing the .NET runtime? If no, then how large is the .net runtime that I need to distribute with my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Xamarin.Mac` apps are self-contained and do not require a separate Mono framework to be installed. Only the portions of the framework that your app uses are included inside the app bundle in order to keep the size as small of possible.

A x86_64 `Xamarin.Mac` Cocca Hello World **Xamarin.Mac Mobile Framework** based App with the linker set to:

- Don't Link: **~48mb**
- Link Framework SDKs Only: **~20mb**
- Link All: **~20mb**

Note: Sizes based on `Xamarin.Mac` 2.9.2.81

Note: Using the other `Xamarin.Mac` frameworks will of course produce slightly larger bundle sizes...

Note: This is a *do nothing* app, so once you start adding assets, content, code, external packages, etc... your app size is going to grow.

`Xamarin.Mac` apps are not compiled via `LLVM` into bit-code and/or machine code like `Xamarin.iOS` apps. There are some *old* email threads floating around that this was begin looked at along with AOTing, but I *assume* lack of demand vs. engineering time required never was justified.

Note: It is possible to use a custom OS-X Mono build that is LLVM-enabled, but I have not done this in x86_64-based Mono OS-X apps for App Store distribution, only local app for private distribution. This is all done outside of Xamarin Studio and not a *supported* configuration. That said and with `xamarin-macios` begin open-source now, if you are using **Xamarin.Mac Mobile Framework** in your OS-X app which is the shared Unified framework, you can wire up an Mono/LLVM-based build environment, but again, not a Xamarin supported configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Dec 2018, Xamarin.Forms + Xamarin.Mac give 16Mb bundle size for a an app with 5+ forms. This is a self-contained application with no dependency on Mono or whatsoever framework installed.